# Electrons response not always returns 'end'

Tags: javascript, json, electron

I'm writting small electron app that reads JSON web service, I noticed that sometimes 'response' object not sending 'end' event. Any idea what I did wrong? 
In addition, my web service works just fine sending multipart chunked data, I can see that as return of console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`).

```js
getDataBtn.addEventListener('click',function(event){
      var autoryzator = document.getElementById('autoryzator').value;
      var kwartal = document.getElementById('kwartal').value;
      var rok = document.getElementById('rok').value;
      console.log( `http://go/ankieta/default/purchase_order?approver=${autoryzator}&qtr=${kwartal}&year=${rok}`);
      var request = net.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `http://go/ankieta/default/purchase_order?approver=${autoryzator}&qtr=${kwartal}&year=${rok}`,
        port: 80
      })
      var authorize = document.getElementById('authorize');
      var jsdata;
      var data='';
      console.log('connecting ...');
      request.on('response', (response) => {
          console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
          console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`)
          response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`)
            var body = chunk.toString('utf8');
            data=data+body
          })
          response.on('end', () => {
            console.log('No more data in response.')
            console.log(data)
            jsdata=JSON.parse(data);
            var data_ = jsdata['data'];
        
        /// some app logic goes here
          })
          response.on('error', (error) => {
            console.log(`ERROR: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
            ret = JSON.stringify(error);
          })
        })
        request.end();

      })
```

Comment: Code isn't very clear, can you include the variables declarations?

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi hope now is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
request.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive, close')
request.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
request.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', '*')
```